# php_intl.dll not working when using php5apache2_4.dll

Tags: php, windows, apache, intl

On a Windows 7 64bit I installed:

- Apache 2.4.23 x86 VC11 Thread safe
- php 5.6.27-Win32-VC11-x86

Apache httpd.conf:

```
...
LoadModule php5_module "D:/devapps/php/php5apache2_4.dll"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir "D:/devapps/php"
...
```

Everything is working fine and with  phpInfo() I see that the loaded PHP.ini is the correct one (PHPIniDir) and the extension intl is enabled:

PHP.ini

```
...
extension_dir = "D:/devapps/php/ext"
...
extension=php_intl.dll
...
```

When I test it with command line:

```
php.exe -c \devapps\php -r "echo '[' . extension_loaded('intl') . ']';"
```

it reports that the extension is loaded correctly (output: [1]) with no warnings.

But if I look at the apache logs, I see the following error:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'D:/devapps/php/ext\php_intl.dll' - Cannot find the specified module.\r\n in Unknown on line 0

and through the web server extension_loaded('intl') is false.

Other extension (like soap or curl) works fine.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

I made a few tests: after copying the icuuc57.dll, icuin57.dll, icuio57.dll to the Apache bin directory the PHP warning disappeared and the extension intl worked correctly through the web server.

> So I solved it in a better manner including the D:\devapps\php on the system %PATH% variable (I have different versions of PHP, so I didn't set it).

It seems that apache is unable to fetch and load those DLL even if they are on the same directory of the php5apache2_4.dll

Answer (score 0):

Check value of the `extension_dir` directive in your *php.ini*.

If it's only *ext*, try changing it to an absolute path, e.g. *D:/devapps/php/ext* (if this is the correct path).

Comment: It's already set with an absolute path (I updated the question)